# Merging services in Gitlab CI

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am experimenting with GitLab CI pipelines and would like to simplyfi the scripts by providing some includes. According to the Gitlab documentation such a workflow is fully supported and deep merging is applied between sections.

So this is what I have:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
include:
  - .base.yml
  - .mariadb.config.yml

job:
  script:
    - mysql -u root -h db -e 'Some SQL statement'
    - <other commands>
```

`.base.yml`

```yaml
variables:
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND: 'noninteractive'

default:
  image: 'php:7.4'
  before_script:
    - 'mkdir -pv /usr/share/man/man1 /usr/share/man/man3 /usr/share/man/man7'
    - '( apt-get -qq update && apt-get -yqq install --no-install-suggests default-jre-headless mariadb-client )'
```

`.mariadb.config.yml`

```yaml
variables:
  FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 'true'
  DB: 'mariadb'

default:
  services:
    - name: 'mariadb:10.6'
      alias: 'db'
      command:
        - '--character-set-server=utf8mb4'
        - '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
        - '--innodb_file_per_table=On'
        - '--wait-timeout=28800'
        - '--skip-log-bin'
      variables:
        MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'yes'
```

I would like to connect to the database with mysql client and do some stuff but all I get is :

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-2)
```

When I merge all this in a single `.gitlab-ci.yml` file everything works as expected.

My error? Gitlab bug?

Comment: There is an opiton in gitlab named `View merged YAML`. Would you please update the question with that output?

Comment: I experimented a bit and what happens is that gitlab does not merge services in default block, it just picks up the one from the last included file...